# Nitro DB initialization pattern using plugin, does this make sense? (nuxt, mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, nuxt.js, nitro

does the concept of initing a db connection then attaching it to the nitroApp context within a plugin make sense?
usage is from api/hello and that does a { db} = useNitroApp()

this does work, im just wondering if this is a good thing to do or is there something better?(in terms of attaching db to the nitroApp context)
this is some test code(ino its no secure):

```
***server/plugins/sql.js
import mysql from 'mysql'
export default defineNitroPlugin((nitro) => {

    const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        user: "users_service",
        password: "123",
        database: "users"
    });
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("DB Connected!");
        nitro.db = con;
    });

    nitro.hooks.hookOnce("close", async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve) => con.end(() => resolve()));
        console.log("db connection closed");
    });
})

***serve/api/hello.js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const { db } = useNitroApp()
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM directory";

    const directoryData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve(result)
        });
    })

    return directoryData
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/25710#issuecomment-1935622896), you should not attach directly to nitroApp, but using context in hooks request event, and get it in route API event

```js
nuxtApp.hooks.hook("request", e => {e.context.[your attach]});

// access it in route
export default defineEventHandler(e => {e.context.[attach]});
```

if you using `useNitroApp()` and destructure it, at `npm run build`, you will see its giving a warning